# form outputs ascii while "accept-charset" is set to utf-8

Tags: php, forms, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

folks, I need you help please.
I have a form with some inputs that expect some special chars. Thats why I want to use utf-8 encoding. It set it in HTML as a meta-tag, in PHP as a header and directly in the form with "accept-charset". Yet, I get the following:

```
var_dump($_POST['name']) => "dagã¶bert" (original input: "dägobert")
var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($_POST['vorname'])); => "ascii"
```

I have absolutely no idea left on what more to do to get this working. I appreciate any hint.

Comment: So you have set this?, just to be sure Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8

Comment: I have set it like this in the HTML-Head
<meta charset="utf-8" />

Answer (score -1):

To make sure, that your web server output (from php) is interpreted as utf-8, you can set the encoding explicitly by calling:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

at the beginning of your php script. It is important that this is called before any other output is done by the script, else an error occurs, that headers could not be set any more.

The `<meta charset="utf-8">` tag is not sufficient. You should use the meta tag as well to provide the encoding even in the case that a user decides to store the page locally and view it later again (when noch Content-Type is provided any more, because the page doesn't come from the web server any more).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But as mentioned, I already have the php-header included in my script and at the very beginning of the script before any output is made. I have also tried both, the shorthand meta tag and the longer version with the content-type included. Both did not work out for me.

Comment: Then try calling `mb_detect_order('UTF-8')` before calling `mb_detect_encoding()`. If it is set to something else, the encoding could be detected wrong. This may help to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Could you then put a little more of your code into the question? I would like to have a look at your form. Is it available online?

Comment: thanks for your time here! Yes, the form is available at `www.werwirsind.pixolatier.at?p=db`. The php has become somewhat complex. I'm happy to post it but I'm not quite sure which part interests you.

Comment: I checked your form and found that it seems to send correct utf-8 coded values, as well as your pages send the correct headers. Could it be that your php uses some output buffering and conversion afterwards before actually printing the output? Pls, check the php code for something like `ob_start()`

Comment: Wow, thanks for your effort! You were absolutely right! I was not using any output buffering but I included an old script I had to prevent SQL-Injection that messed around with the output. Thank you so much!